# Q: Derivatives of function which includes a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We have $g(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $|g(x)| \leq M$  $∀x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M$ is a constant. We also have $f(x)=(x-1)^2g(x)$.
I must show that $f(x)$ is derivative at $x=1$ and show that the second derivative $f''(x)$ may not exist for $x=1$ for some $g(x)$.

Haven't really tried anything yet, looking for some tips here. Thanks in advance!